# Possible to update application status?

Tags: support, questions, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently was hired on Stack Overflow Jobs. *Yay*. But today my recruiter asked me to validate the application - it's still in the "Offer" status.

I looked for a way to validate it, but didn't find any button, link, questions / answers on meta nor any documentation.

- Is there a way for applicant / recruiter to set status of applications?
- If yes, did the applicant have to validate status? It would be fair.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, congratulations and best of lucks on your new gig! it makes us super happy having played a little part in that.

I'm not exactly sure what your recruiter is asking you to do. We have a simple internal applicant tracking system (ATS) where they can manage their applicants (and the last stage is "Offer"), but there's no extra step to confirm that a hire has been made, either by you or by them.

They could also be using an external ATS, and in that case... you should ask them for clarifications.

Comment: Ok, so `offer` is the last stage possible, that the answer I was looking for. Thx :)