# Custom candidate stages in Stack Overflow Talent

Tags: support, stack-overflow-talent

Is it possible to create custom stages for candidates in Stack Overflow Talent?

The current Stages appear as:

[image: New, In Review, Interview, and Offer.]

I'd like to add more stages based on our internal hiring process but haven't seen any place to do that.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, no.

[source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353866/possible-to-update-application-status)

("*the last stage is "Offer"*" makes me think if "offer" is the last stage, stages are statics.)